# Python Regex Script sort and print to new document

Tags: python, regex, export

so I am trying to write some code that will scan a .txt file with a bunch of jumble in between IDs. I want to find specific strings, create a new line before them, and print to a new document. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
from__future__import print_function
import re
NDoc = raw_input("Enter name of new document")".txt"
log = open("C:Python27\NDoc.txt", 'w')
file = raw_input("Enter a file to be sorted")
xfile = open(file)

for line in xfile:
    l=line.strip()
    n=re.sub("(\B)(?=((MTH|ENG|SCN|HST)[|]))","\n",line)

if len(n) > 0:
    nl=split.("\n")
    for item in nl:
        print(item)
```

When I run this, I get an Eroor [errno2] No such file or directory: 'xxx' where xxx = whatever my input was for the variable "file."

I'm not sure what to do cause I am pretty sure I am entering files in the directory.

Also, on a side note, will this code create a new file and print into it with the open('filename', 'w') line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `".txt"` which trows this error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` so you should use `+".txt"`. The same for the `file` variable.

```
>>> NDoc = raw_input("Enter name of new document")".txt"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> NDoc = raw_input("Enter name of new document") + ".txt"
Enter name of new documentsomefile
>>> NDoc
'somefile.txt'
>>>
```

Comment: Okay, this helped me get past that error but I have a couple more questions.

Do you know how I can get the code to create a new file with the name placed in the variable "NDoc"?

Also, my code isn't appropriately creating a new line before the parameters above (such as MTH, SCN, etc) if it has a | before it (ie: MTH|lkafahlfa||HST|lkhadflh would all still end up on the same line when it is supposed to split). Is this a problem with my \B parameter?

Comment: I am glad that helped. I suggest to post your new question in a new post, otherwise, this post will get a bit confusing. Usually the best practice here is not to pile up more questions when one is answered. BTW you can click the right answer for this question and then I will look for your new post and post the new answer for you there.

Comment: Okay, I marked this as answered, however, I can't make another post for about 55 more minutes.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I should still be here then. I will look for your post then.

Comment: @ScottT this is how you can create a new text file with the name stored in `NDoc`. It is simple, all you have to do is this: `f = open(NDoc, 'a')` this will create the file and puts it in the same directory where your `.py` code is.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely another thing I was looking for!